# Resource allocation and automatic deallocation

Tags: c++

In my application I got many instances of **class CDbaOciNotifier**. They all share a pointer to only one instance of **class OCIEnv**.

What I like to achieve is that allocation and deallocation of the resource **class OCIEnv** will be handled automatically inside **class CDbaOciNotifier**.

The desired behaviour is, with the first instance of **class CDbaOciNotifier** the environment will be created, after that all following notifiers use that same environment. With the destruction of the last notifier, the environment will be destroyed too (call to custom deleter).
**Later on, this cycle can start again with the creation of a new environment.**

What I've got so far (using a static factory method to create notifiers):

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "boost\noncopyable.hpp"

class CDbaOciNotifier : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:

    virtual ~CDbaOciNotifier(void);

    static std::auto_ptr<CDbaOciNotifier> createNotifier(const std::string &tnsName, const std::string &user, const std::string &password);

private:
    CDbaOciNotifier(OCIEnv* envhp);

    // All notifiers share one environment
    static OCIEnv* m_ENVHP;

    // Custom deleter
    static void freeEnvironment(OCIEnv *env);

    OCIEnv* m_envhp;
};
```

CPP:

```
#include "DbaOciNotifier.h"

using namespace std;

OCIEnv* CDbaOciNotifier::m_ENVHP = 0;

CDbaOciNotifier::~CDbaOciNotifier(void)
{
}

CDbaOciNotifier::CDbaOciNotifier(OCIEnv* envhp)
                :m_envhp(envhp)
{

}

void CDbaOciNotifier::freeEnvironment(OCIEnv *env)
{
    OCIHandleFree((dvoid *) env, (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_ENV);
    *env = null;
}

auto_ptr<CDbaOciNotifier> CDbaOciNotifier::createNotifier(const string &tnsName, const string &user, const string &password)
{
    if(!m_ENVHP)
    {
        OCIEnvCreate( (OCIEnv **) &m_ENVHP, OCI_EVENTS|OCI_OBJECT, (dvoid *)0,
            (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, size_t)) 0,
            (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *, size_t))0,
            (void (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *)) 0,
            (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0 );
    }

    //shared_ptr<OCIEnv> spEnvhp(m_ENVHP, freeEnvironment); ...got so far...

    return auto_ptr<CDbaOciNotifier>(new CDbaOciNotifier(m_ENVHP));
}
```

I'd like to avoid counting references (notifiers) myself, and use something like shared_ptr.

Do you see an easy solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on in your code.  Here is the solution, but simplified to just the bare essentials.

```
class CDbaOciNotifier
{
public:
   CDbaOciNotifier() :
      m_resource(get_env())
   { }

private:
   shared_ptr<OCIEnv> m_env;

   struct Delete_env
   {
      void operator()(OCIEnv* env)
      {
         OCIHandleFree( ... );
      }
   };

   static shared_ptr<OCIEnv> get_env()
   {
        // make sure a mutex is involved if CDbaOciNotifier
        // can be constructed concurrently.

        static weak_ptr<OCIEnv> s_env;

        shared_ptr<OCIEnv> env = s_env.lock();
        if( ! env )
        {
            OCIEnv* env_ptr = OCIEnvCreate( ... );
            env.reset( env_ptr, Delete_env() );
            s_env = env;
        }
        return env;
   }
};
```

As written you cannot construct `CDbaOciNotifier` concurrently.  You'll need a static mutex to protect `s_env` if you want that ability.

The `weak_ptr` needs to be a function local static otherwise you're app might explode if a global or static `CDbaOciNotifier` is created (static initialization order is undefined).

Comment: Caspin, thanks a lot for your explanation and the code example. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
// In .h file
class CDbaOciNotifier
{
    // ...
    private:
        static shared_ptr<OCIEnv> envPtr;
};

// In .cpp file
// Write freeEnvironment as a free function.
shared_ptr<OCIEnv> CDbaOciNotifier::envPtr(new OCIEnv, freeEnvironment);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kristo. But this doesn't show the needed behaviour. 
In your example the OCIEnv will be created once for the application (it's static, so that's expected). But I will NOT be deleted when the last instance of CDbaOciNotifier is destroyed, but when the application is unloaded. Also the cycle createEnvironment....freeEnvironment can be traversed many times during application live time. I added a remark in my original question for clarification.